# Ordinary Differential Equations with undetermined coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I had this question on an exam.

Solve the following without using series:
(t^2)y'' - (2t)y' - 10y = 7t5

I begin by factoring out (y^k)
i.e.

(y^k) (r(r-1) - 2r -10) = 0
Solving for r, I got:

(r^2) + 3r - 10 = 0
Therefore: r = 5, -2

From this I get:
y(t) = C1(t^5) + C2(t^-2)

However, I'm having trouble finding the second half of the solution.
I understand that I should set Y1(t) = t^s(At^5+Bt^4+Ct^3+Dt^2+Et+F)
And s should be the lowest value so that there aren't any repeated values from the original equation in the solution. So should I set s equal to 3, since if s were equal to 2, then the (t^2) would be repeated. I'm kind of stuck and was wondering if anyone could help, specifically with finding the 2nd half of the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at [this MathJax basic tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your maths properly. Also, what do you mean by factoring out $y^k$? Are you trying to get the characteristic polynomial? And what is $r$?

Comment: Is the right side supposed to be $7t^5$? Please type exponents and subscripts so they all appear  in the right place.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm going to read the tutorial and reformat my question. But demosthene seems to have read it properly below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [this MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and write your maths properly to avoid any confusion.

I'm going to assume you meant that your differential equation is:
$$t^2y''-2ty'-10y=7t^5$$
The solution of this equation will be the sum of the complementary solution $y_c(t)=c_1t^{-2}+c_2t^5$ and the particular solution $y_p(t)$, which we have yet to find. One way to find to it is as follows.

Let us first compute the Wronskian of $t^{-2}$ and $t^5$:
$$\mathcal{W}=\begin{vmatrix}t^{-2}&t^5\\\dfrac{d}{dt}\left[t^{-2}\right]&\dfrac{d}{dt}\left[t^5\right]\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}t^{-2}&t^5\\-2t^{-3}&5t^4\end{vmatrix}=7t^2$$
We can divide the differential equation by $t^2$:
$$y''-\dfrac{2y'}{t}-\dfrac{10y}{t^2}=7t^3$$
We now introduce the functions $u(t)$ and $v(t)$, defined as:
$$u(t)=-\int\dfrac{7t^3\cdot t^5}{\mathcal{W}}dt=-\dfrac{t^7}{7}$$
$$v(t)=\int\dfrac{7t^3\cdot t^{-2}}{\mathcal{W}}dt=\ln(t)$$
The particular solution is then given by:
$$y_p(t)=u(t)\cdot t^{-2}+v(t)\cdot t^5=-\dfrac{t^5}{7}+t^5\ln(t)$$
Finally, the general solution is:
$$y(t)=y_c(t)+y_p(t)=c_1t^{-2}+c_2t^5-\dfrac{t^5}{7}+t^5\ln(t)$$
$$y(t)=c_1t^{-2}+c_2t^5+t^5\ln(t)$$
(where in the last step the $-1/7$ coefficient of $t^5$ has been absorbed in $c_2$).

Comment: Thank you very much. This makes perfect sense, and I'll make sure to format my questions properly next time.